# Object has no method 'S3Uploader' with rails s3_direct_upload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, zurb-foundation

*tl;dr:  When custom jQuery functions disappear in development, you may need to delete the previously precompiled public/assets/javascripts/application.js file*

I have a rails app I had deployed to Heroku, and then wanted to add s3_direct_upload to let users upload files to Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3.  I modified the paperclip_demo app at https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip_demo using the nice comprehensive tutorial at http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

But, while the modified paperclip_demo worked, when I tried to migrate that code to my more complex app, at the following Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#s3_uploader').S3Uploader(
    { 
      remove_completed_progress_bar: false,
      progress_bar_target: $('#uploads_container')
    }
  );
  $('#s3_uploader').bind('s3_upload_failed', function(e, content) {
    return alert(content.filename + ' failed to upload');
  });
});
```

I got the error in the Javascript debugger of the browser

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'S3Uploader'
```

However, s3_direct_upload.js was being included, and included the line

```
 $.fn.S3Uploader = function(options) {...}
```

which should have defined the S3Uploader function for jQuery.

I noticed that, although all of the jQuery Javascripts were separately included in the generated .html, the application.js was also included, and included what appeared to be the compressed version of jQuery as well.  My app/assets/javascripts/application.js included the line to load the Zurb Foundation javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted at [JS files double-included in rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437574/js-files-double-included-in-rails-app), when the Rails Javascripts seem to be double loaded, the problem may be that you have previously precompiled the assets, as generally required for deploying to Heroku.

As noted there, the solution is to delete public/assets/application.js (and application.js.gz)

When I did that, s3_direct_upload worked for my larger application.